# Passing information when activity is calling self

Tags: java, android

I am working on an application that does the following. You are given a group of radio buttons and when you click one radio button it generates a notification. When the used taps the notification he is brought back to the app. The only problem is that now no button looks pressed. How do i fix it? Should I do that with intent extras or what?

My code is below.

```
private void DispatchNotification(String numValue,String nameValue,CompoundButton button){
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);

        PendingIntent pIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder= new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setAutoCancel(false);
        builder.setContentTitle("Just Title");
        builder.setContentText(nameValue+" "+numValue);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult);

        builder.setContentIntent(pIntent);
        builder.setOngoing(true);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        manager.notify(8,builder.build());
    }
```

The CompoundButton button is the radio key that i want to return pressed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Comment: What do you mean no button looks pressed?

Comment: He wants the button looks pressed after the activity is recreated

Comment: Yes, you should use intent extras to tell the activity which button should "look pressed"